# jQuery datatables filtering - the fifth parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, arguments, datatables

I am using jQuery datatables in a small project I am working on. At this point I am just setting up some filtering functions to make the table more user friendly. The documentation for the filter function tells me:

> Input parameters:
>
> {string}: String to filter the table on
>
> {int|null}: Column to limit filtering to
>
> {bool} [default=false]: Treat as regular expression or not
>
> {bool} [default=true]: Perform smart filtering or not
>
> {bool} [default=true]: Show the input global filter in it's input box(es)
>
> {bool} [default=true]: Do case-insensitive matching (true) or not (false)

I understand all but the fifth -

> Show the input global filter in it's input box(es)

Some of my guesses:

- It determines whether or not to show add the applied filter to the input box in the upper toolbar of the datatable. (Nope, nothing shows up in there whether I have it set to true or false, and whether I specify a column or use global filtering)
- It determines whether or not this input box shows up at all, same as the `bFilter` property of the initialization object. Seems weird to have the option here, in the method that uses the filtering function, so I doubt it (plus, if doesn't disappear when I run the method with ("test",null,false,true,false)`
- It determines whether the text already entered into the global filtering input is taken into account for the new filter (nope, tried filtering with the text box then filtering with the API, supplying false for this parameter - the result had both filters applied.)

Does anyone know what it does??? I mean, in all seriousness I am likely to only use the first two, but I'd like to know what the option is before I decide to ignore it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simply says whether to display the searched term in the search input field.

With value false: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kV7Hy/1/)

```
oTable.fnFilter('firefox', null, false, true, false, true);
```

Look at the top right text field - it is empty

With value true: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kV7Hy/2/)

```
oTable.fnFilter('firefox', null, false, true, true, true);
```

Look at the top right text field - it is displaying the search text `firfox`

Comment: I almost replied that wasn't the case, as I had tested for it, however it does work... my initial tests must have had some other problem. Thank you very much